# plotting 3d vectors

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector, matplotlib-3d

I am trying to plot vectors in 3d using matplotlib.  I used the following code based on a previous example of plotting 2d vectors but added components for 3d vectors.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

soa =np.array( [ [0,0,1,1,-2,0], [0,0,2,1,1,0],[0,0,3,2,1,0],[0,0,4,0.5,0.7,0]]) 

X,Y,Z,U,V,W = zip(*soa)
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.quiver(X,Y,Z,U,V,W,angles='xyz',scale_units='xyz',scale=1,color='b')
ax.set_xlim([-1,10])
ax.set_ylim([-1,10])
ax.set_zlim([10,1])
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Any ideas on how to tweak this to make a 3d vector plot?

Answer (score 33):

You need to use Axes3D from mplot3d in mpl_toolkits, then set the subplot projection to 3d:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

soa = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1, -2, 0], [0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0], [0, 0, 4, 0.5, 0.7, 0]])

X, Y, Z, U, V, W = zip(*soa)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.quiver(X, Y, Z, U, V, W)
ax.set_xlim([-1, 0.5])
ax.set_ylim([-1, 1.5])
ax.set_zlim([-1, 8])
plt.show()
```

**Note:** Older version of matplotlib often give errors for this code. Try to use at least version 1.5

[image: produced_output]

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested but I get an error:  AttributeError: 'Quiver' object has no attribute 'do_3d_projection     how do I resolve this?

Comment: @jms1980 That's odd, I've tried it in python 2 and python 3 and it works fine for me. What error are you getting?

Comment: @jms1980 What version of matplotlib do you have? I'm using the latest stable version 1.4.2.

Comment: matplotlib 1.3.1.  How do you get the version 1.4.2  I did a sudo yum install to get mine.

Comment: @jms1980 If you're using fedora (an assumption based on the fact you use yum), then 1.3.1 seems to be the latest version available through the normal repos. You can build matplotlib from source, there are instructions available [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html). This would let you use the latest version.

Comment: You could also do `pip install matplotlib --upgrade`.

Comment: in addition to Tim B's answer, the version of matplolib that you use matters a lot. matplotlib 1.3.1 seems to have issues that are resolved by 1.4.2 and especially now by 1.5.1.

Answer (score 5):

From other answers and comments, there is clearly a difference between matplotlib versions. However, I believe Tim B's answer does not answer the question. The quivers plotted do not represent the given vectors, since their magnitudes are not properly represented. Also, the arrowheads appear to sit at the intended start points of the vectors.

The following, adapted from the code in the previous answer, produces the desired result in `python2.7` with `matplotlib1.5.3`. To visualise a vector, setting the pivot point to `pivot='tail'` and scaling the quiver by the magnitude of the vector has the desired effect. The quiver arrowhead is scaled as a ratio of the quiver length. Here I divide the scaling factor by the magnitude of the vector to make all arrowheads the same size with `arrow_length_ratio=0.3/vlength`.

Bad points - My code isn't very compact. I've had to provide X,Y,Z,U,V,W in an unpacked form in order to use different kwargs for each call to ax.quiver. If anyone can suggest an edit that packs kwargs I'd be extremely grateful.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

vectors=np.array( [ [0,0,1,1,-2,0], [0,0,2,1,1,0],[0,0,3,2,1,0],[0,0,4,0.5,0.7,0]]) 
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for vector in vectors:
    v = np.array([vector[3],vector[4],vector[5]])
    vlength=np.linalg.norm(v)
    ax.quiver(vector[0],vector[1],vector[2],vector[3],vector[4],vector[5],
            pivot='tail',length=vlength,arrow_length_ratio=0.3/vlength)
ax.set_xlim([-4,4])
ax.set_ylim([-4,4])
ax.set_zlim([0,4])
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()
```

Output:
[Plot of vectors as quivers with matplotlib-1.5.3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq9f7.png)

Comment: In matplotlib2.0.0 the quiver lengths are properly scaled for this functionality, so `ax.quiver(vector[0],vector[1],vector[2],vector[3],vector[4],vector[5],
            pivot='tail',length=vlength,arrow_length_ratio=0.3/vlength)` should be changed to `ax.quiver(vector[0],vector[1],vector[2],vector[3],vector[4],vector[5],
            pivot='tail',arrow_length_ratio=0.3/vlength)`, or back to `ax.quiver(X, Y, Z, U, V, W, pivot='tail')` with a zipped array (see Tim B's answer) if you don't need scaled arrowheads.