# How to plot vectors in 3D in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector, 3d

I have 2 vectors in 3D with these components:

```
a = [1,0,0]
b = [0,1,0]
```

These vector are orthogonal. I want to simply plot these vectors in 3D. I have looked at a matplotlib demo [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/quiver3d.html)

However it is not what I want to do. I only want to plot these 2 vectors (arrows on head). Is there any way to do it in python? 
Thanks!

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/27025181/11045279

Comment: Old post that might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140163/plotting-a-3d-cube-a-sphere-and-a-vector-in-matplotlib